# Speed-up google Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I wanted to know how we can speed up the existing Airflow cluster.

Currently, I have increased the resources for the existing cluster resources added both horizontal and vertical scaling not sure what else I need to do more here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your both horizontal and vertical scaling? and have you noticed any difference?

Comment: Yes I have given enough resource for vertical scaling and added 3 nodes of the same size for horizontal scaling and I get the boost as well but I feel that it is getting a bit slower, I read somewhere that our backend DB also need to be clean up after some time but as I am using the google composer I did not know where I should log in to clean my backend database as our composer is around a 1 year, hoping that this could solve this performance impact

Comment: 1) have you noticed any improvement? 2) which version are you running on right now?